# DlgDirList winapi c++

Tags: winapi, c++

Хочу вывести список файлов и каталогов. Использую DlgDirList.

```
DlgDirList(hDlg,(LPWSTR)"c:\\",IDC_LIST1,0, DDL_DIRECTORY|DDL_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Так оно не работает (синтаксических ошибок нет - что-то с памятью видимо). НО! Если не задавать ей путь (просто ""). То она работает, причем выводит только список каталогов в текущей папке. Если поставить последний пареметр - 0, она выведет файлы в корне текущего диска.
Я так понял ей не нравится путь
Кто нибудь знает как ей пользоваться по-человечьи???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
DlgDirList(hDlg, _TEXT("C:\\"), IDC_LIST1, 0, DDL_DIRECTORY | DDL_EXCLUSIVE);
```

или так:

```
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = _TEXT("C:\\");

DlgDirList(hDlg, path, IDC_LIST1, 0, DDL_DIRECTORY | DDL_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Не работает(

Comment: Второй вариант действительно заработал. Спасибо большое.
Я просто только начинаю изучать winapi.